# Banco de dados com QRCODE

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, qrcode

Bom dia pessoal, quero gerar um QRCODE que puxe informações de um banco de dados, no android farei o leitor de QRCODE usando alguma api zxing ou barcode. Alguem já fez alguma coisa do tipo? exemplo passo o id do produto no QRCODE, e o leitor retorna as informações do produto. Algum uma dica do que usar para fazer isso?